# How to retrieve payloadString from onMessageArrived to constructor?

Tags: android, react-native

Please check the code. I want to retrieve payloadString data from onMessageArrived to constructor. How to do that? Basically, I want to store all the JSON data in Asyncstorage as well as also want to apply some logic within the constructor. That's why I want to retrieve data from onMessageArrived to constructor. Thanks in Advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import init from 'react_native_mqtt';
import { AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

init({
  size: 10000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  enableCache: true,
  sync: {},
});



export default class MqttLog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('iot.eclipse.org', 443, 'uname');
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    client.connect({ onSuccess: this.onConnect, useSSL: true });


    this.state = {
      text: ['ELOGIC'],
      client,
    };

    this.onMessageArrived.bind(this);
  }



  onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    client.subscribe('WORLD');
    console.log('connect');
  };

  onConnectionLost = responseObject => {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      var connectionLostMessage = `connection lost: ${responseObject.errorMessage}`;
      console.log(connectionLostMessage);

    }
  };

  onMessageArrived = message => {

    var msg = message.payloadString;
    var messageResult = `${msg}`;
    console.log(messageResult);

  };

  render() {


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve this by using async storage. When data will come from mqtt, immediately I push the data within async storage and then retrieve from async storage using key-value pair within the constructor.